# How to extract specific numbers from files to solve an equation?

Tags: scripts

I have multiple files that look like this:

```
//   copyright kkshlglkf
//   lhafslghldk
//   rsghlgsrlskl
//   sgkg
//   sgrjgrs
//   Memory:   BDRAM_SP
//   Bits:     32
//   Mux:      8
//   ladhdal:  sdj
//   zdfjhael: apfiehad
     slhgslfkghlkj
     slgdhlgfdkkdf
     Dataoutstage: None;
     TransparentMode: None;
     CellName: BDRAM_SP;
MemoryTemplate(BDRAM_SP)
{
 afljefkaf
 aslhkldfjfa
 fihhfejksgj
 dfhdhsgjshgf
 zdkjjgshgf
 sjfhfjkh
 sfdkjssjfh
```

I need to extract the numbers `32` and `8` and then calculate the result of

```
sum=b * (0.004+(c * 0.00008));
```

where `b=32` and `c=4`.

The result should be written to the file as `Result: sum;`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You only provided two lines. Do all lines look like your example ?  or are there any different lines ?

Comment: during a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42548/discussion-on-answer-by-wayne-yux-how-the-specific-string-form-diffenerent-lines) with OP, I got some more information about the problem and edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following perl `script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                          
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my$file (@ARGV)
{
    open(IN,'<',$file) or die $!;
    open(OUT,'>',$file.".result") or die $!;
    my$b;
    my$c;
    my$sum;
  while(<IN>)
  {
      ($b)=$_=~/(\d+)/ if $_=~/Bits/;
      ($c)=$_=~/(\d+)/ if $_=~/Mux/;
      print OUT $_;
  }
  print STDERR "found values in ",$file,":\n";
  print STDERR "Bits: ",$b,"\nMux: ",$c,"\n";

    $sum=$b * (0.004+($c * 0.00008));
    print STDERR "writing sum (",$sum,") to the output ",$file,".result\n";
    print OUT "Result: ",$sum,";\n";

    close OUT or die $!;
    close IN or die $!;
}
```

It searches the input file for the strings *Bits* and *Mux*, extracts the following numbers and prints the result of the equation (`$sum=$b * (0.004+($c * 0.00008))`) to the output file as `Result: <number>;`. The output file is named as `input-file.result`.

Running it on your example file:

```
$ perl myscript.pl file.txt
found values in file.txt:
Bits: 32
Mux: 8
writing sum (0.14848) to the output file.txt.result
```

The content of `file.txt.result`:

```
//   copyright kkshlglkf
//   lhafslghldk
//   rsghlgsrlskl
//   sgkg
//   sgrjgrs
//   Memory:   BDRAM_SP
//   Bits:     32
//   Mux:      8
//   ladhdal:  sdj
//   zdfjhael: apfiehad
     slhgslfkghlkj
     slgdhlgfdkkdf
     Dataoutstage: None;
     TransparentMode: None;
     CellName: BDRAM_SP;
MemoryTemplate(BDRAM_SP)
{
 afljefkaf
 aslhkldfjfa
 fihhfejksgj
 dfhdhsgjshgf
 zdkjjgshgf
 sjfhfjkh
 sfdkjssjfh
Result: 0.14848;
```

If you want to use the script with multiple input files, you can run it as

```
perl myscript.pl file1 file2 file3 ...
```

This will then create the output files `file1.result`, `file2.result` and so on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42548/discussion-on-answer-by-wayne-yux-how-the-specific-string-form-diffenerent-lines).

Comment: @shri please visit the chat link above, you will be able to access that one.

Comment: @terdon thanks for moving. I did not get the automated message to move it.